# Browserify command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

Quick question, when I run browserify index.js -o app.js from mac terminal, I get command not found. I have done npm install -g browserify but still no luck. Any idea why I am getting this?

Thank you

It was easier for me to do a gist than to paste here:
https://gist.github.com/pertrai1/4ccf77e7b31cb5628b5d

Comment: Hey, I am on unix and tried both with still no luck :-(

Comment: can you paste the console log when you rerun `npm install -g browserify`?

Comment: So you should have a binding `/Users/robsimpson/npm/bin/browserify -> /Users/robsimpson/npm/lib/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js` now. Does `/Users/robsimpson/npm/bin/browserify` work when you try to run it?

Answer (score 19):

Just install it in a global space like this if you need to run it from the command line.

`npm install browserify -g`

You may need to run

`npm uninstall browserify -g` fist just to be sure you don't have false aliases.

Comment: This is necessary but not sufficient, since that will still not add the command to your PATH. See my answer.

Comment: I see, sorry, I was not reading the whole thread, but this must work, eventually.

Comment: No need for apologies, nobody can know everything :)

Comment: Worked for me, since it's often used globally I forgot to put it in my `dev-dependencies`

Comment: Works for me. Be sure to run  npm uninstall browserify -g  then npm install browserify -g

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin/`

Then, to actually have this take effect in your terminal session, execute `source ~/.bashrc`.

At this point you can execute `browserify`, as well as potentially many other commands. Check out `~/.npm-global/bin/` to see what's become available.

Answer (score 2):

I could not get `browserify` to work either.

Running `~/.npm/bin/browserify` does work.

Other packages seem to run fine (phantomjs for instance).

A workaround fix seems to be adding `alias browserify='~/.npm/bin/browserify'` to your `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

It is an old post but I believe people are still facing the same problem, like me.

This was how I solved my problem:

```
<your project folder>/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js main.js -o bundle.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install locally `npm install browserify`, you can use this method to execute the browserify command.

`node_modules/.bin/browserify`

For example:
[broweserify command example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzZt4.png)

Extra tips:

Add this command to your `packages.js` file:

```js
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "bundle": "node_modules/.bin/browserify index.js > bundle.js"
  },
```

Then everytime you want to bundle you file just hit `npm run bundle`

Hope it helps you guys out there..

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the `browserify` command has not been installed at all (can happen for example if you're running Homebrew on old unsupported Mac OS X versions), an alternative is to call it via `node`, for example:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules
node -e 'require("browserify")("input.js").bundle().pipe(fs.createWriteStream("output.js"))'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a Mac user I had to add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/

in ~.bash_profile
```

Why Cellar path i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the default zsh shell and I came across a solution: `sudo npm install browserify -g`

After that `sudo browserify` AND `browserify` worked flawlessly. I guess mine was a simple permissions issue.

I'm running Ventura.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34308041)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to solve it within project directory, not by global

```bash
npm install browserify
npx browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```