# -bash: browserify: command not found

Tags: browserify, npm-install

I am trying to install web pack with browserify with this:

```
browserify main.js > bundle.js
```

following these instructions: https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto

Terminal keeps showing:

```
browserify: command not found
```

even after running

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Tried using solutions from [Cannot find module 'browserify'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472522/cannot-find-module-browserify/23244216#23244216) and [Browserify command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947262/browserify-command-not-found).

Here's the console window:

https://gist.github.com/robojukie/b6ca2443f02511d05f372eefc132e3a0

How can I figure out what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A better answer is [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/916#issuecomment-57870379). To quote:

> Make sure that `npm config get prefix`/bin is in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
node_modules/.bin/browserify main.js > bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed NPM with Brew test this

```
brew uninstall npm 

brew install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post but I believe people are still facing the same problem like me, so this was my solution:

```
<your project folder>/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js main.js -o bundle.js
```